# How to mix std::string with Win32 functions that take char[] buffers?

Tags: c++, string, stl, winapi

There are a number of Win32 functions that take the address of a buffer, such as `TCHAR[256]`, and write some data to that buffer. It may be less than the size of the buffer or it may be the entire buffer.

Often you'll call this in a loop, for example to read data off a stream or pipe. In the end I would like to efficiently return a string that has the complete data from all the iterated calls to retrieve this data. I had been thinking to use `std::string` since it's += is optimized in a similar way to Java or C#'s `StringBuffer.append()`/`StringBuilder.Append()` methods, favoring speed instead of memory.

But I'm not sure how best to co-mingle the `std::string` with Win32 functions, since these functions take the `char[]` to begin with. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string` has a function `c_str()` that returns its equivalent C-style string. (`const char *`)

Further, `std::string` has overloaded assignment operator that takes a C-style string as input.

e.g. Let `ss` be `std::string` instance and `sc` be a C-style string then the interconversion can be performed as :

```
ss = sc; // from C-style string to std::string
sc = ss.c_str(); // from std::string to C-style string
```

**UPDATE :**

As Mike Weller pointed out, If `UNICODE` macro is defined, then the strings will be `wchar_t*` and hence you would have to use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: Also note that TCHAR will change depending on the value of the UNICODE macro. If UNICODE is defined, then the strings will be wchar_t* and you would have to use std::wstring instead.

Comment: writing directly to a `std::string` internal buffer can be dangerous, since the string also stores things like the length which might be invalid if you do this.

Comment: Idan is correct. Don't use std::string for a function that will write to the string buffer.

Comment: Using std::string as a memory buffer is incorrect because it is not guarantied by current standard to be contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 11):

If the argument is **input-only** use `std::string` like this

```
std::string text("Hello");
w32function(text.c_str());
```

If the argument is **input/output** use `std::vector<char>` instead like this:

```
std::string input("input");
std::vector<char> input_vec(input.begin(), input.end());
input_vec.push_back('\0');
w32function(&input_vec[0], input_vec.size());
// Now, if you want std::string again, just make one from that vector:
std::string output(&input_vec[0]);
```

If the argument is **output-only** also use `std::vector<Type>` like this:

```
// allocates _at least_ 1k and sets those to 0
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(1024, 0);
w32function(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
// use 'buffer' vector now as you see fit
```

You can also use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` and `std::vector<TCHAR>` if needed.

You can read more on the subject in the book **Effective STL** by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than std::string, I would suggest to use `std::vector`, and use `&v.front()` while using `v.size()`.  Make sure to have space already allocated!

You have to be careful with `std::string` and binary data.

```
s += buf;//will treat buf as a null terminated string
s += std::string(buf, size);//would work
```

Comment: it would probably be wise to set an initial size for the vector in the ctor, or alternatively call `resize()` on it. then pass it's `size()` as the length of the buffer.

Comment: @Mike Weller : Thanks for the down vote... I don't see what your point is here... how about .data()?  Of course I know what .c_str() does, but the OP said that the functions take in a buffer, and for arbitrary binary data, it's better to use std::vector rather than std::string.

Comment: Note that you either need to create the vector with size-setting constructor, or call resize() on it.

Comment: Ok so how would you use vector? I want to call for instance Win32's ReadFile() function, which takes LPVOID lpBuffer. How can you pass in the vector so that ReadFile ends up appending to what's already there? Or is there no clean way of doing this?

Comment: What about TCHAR buffer[256]; wstring ws; ws.append(buffer); ? Also it's worth noting that the data being read is a string.

Comment: std::vector<char> vc(100); size_t x = (last read amount); ReadFile(..., vc.begin()+x, vc.size()-x,...);

Answer (score 2):

- You need a compatible string type: `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` is a good choice.
- For input only arguments, you can use the .c_str() method.
- For buffers, the choice is slightly less clear:

std::basic_string is not guaranteed to use contiguous storage like std::vector is. However, all std::basic_string implementations I've seen do use contiguous storage, and the C++ standards committee consider the missing guarantee to be a defect in the standard. The defect has been corrected in the C++0x draft.

If you're willing to bend the rules ever so slightly - with no negative consequences - you can use &(*aString.begin()) as a pointer to a TCHAR buffer of length aString.size(). Otherwise, you're stuck with std::vector for now.

Here's what the C++ standard committee have to say about contiguous string storage:

> Not standardizing this existing
>   practice does not give implementors
>   more freedom. We thought it might a
>   decade ago. But the vendors have
>   spoken both with their
>   implementations, and with their voice
>   at the LWG meetings. The
>   implementations are going to be
>   contiguous no matter what the standard
>   says. So the standard might as well
>   give string clients more design
>   choices.